# Problems Integrating Hadoop 3.x on Flink cluster

Tags: hdfs, apache-flink

I am facing some issues while trying to integrate Hadoop 3.x version on a Flink cluster. My goal is to use HDFS as a persistent storage and store checkpoints. I am currectly using **Flink 1.13.1** and **HDFS 3.3.1**. The error that I am getting while trying to submit a job is that HDFS is not supported as a file system. In the standalone version, this error was solved by specifying the *HADOOP_CLASSPATH* on my local machine. As a next step I applied the  solution above in all the machines that are used in my cluster and in the standalone version I managed to successfully submit my jobs in all of them without facing any issues. However, when I started modifying the configurations to setup my cluster (by specifying the IPs of my machines) that problem came up once again. What I am missing?

In Hadoop 2.x there are the pre-bundled jar files in the official flink download page that would solve similar issues in the past but that's not the case with Hadoop 3.x versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough to set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` on every machine in the cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, however as I mentioned in my initial post it does not seem to work. The hadoop related env variables that I set in my .bashrc file are the following 

`export HADOOP_HOME=$HOME/hadoop`
`export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop`  
`export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME`  
`export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME`  
`export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME`
`export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME`  
`export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin`  
`export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)`

Comment: That's unlikely to work because in a cluster, flink probably isn't running logged in as you.

Comment: Ok, so how should I tackle that? Should I define the env variables somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, but the details depend on how your cluster is deployed.

Comment: That actually helped a lot, after defining my env variables in the `/etc/profile` everything worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with a similar issue, the answer proposed by David worked for me in the end. The detail that I was missing was in the definition of the environment variables.

In my initial attempts, I was using the `.bashrc` script to permanently define my environment variables. This works in the standalone cluster which is not the case with a distributed cluster due to the scope of the script. What actually worked for me was defining my variables(and *$HADOOP_CLASSPATH*) in the `/etc/profile`

I also managed to find another solution while was struggling with HADOOP_CLASSPATH. As I mentioned in my initial post, in Hadoop 2.x there are pre-bundled jar files in the official Flink download page to support HDFS integration, which is not the case in Hadoop 3.x. I found the following maven repository page and after testing all of the existing jars I managed to find one that worked in my case. To be more precise, for **Hadoop 3.3.1** the `3.1.1.7.2.8.0-224-9.0` jar (Placed the jar in the $FLINK_HOME/lib) worked. While it is not an "official solution" it seems to solve the issue.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-shaded-hadoop-3-uber?repo=cloudera-repos